# How to locate a rogue SELECT statement in an Access frontend?

Tags: sql, sql-server, ms-access, blocking

I have two version of my access frontend. One for Access 2003 which is still being run by a few computers not yet upgraded to Access2010 and Win7, the Acces2010 version unfortunately is caused in Access crash in 2003 at close of the mainform that I have been unable to fix. Backend is SqlServer 2005 SqlExpress version.

Therefore I am stuck with the older frontend for 2003 people, who fortunately don't need the newer capabilities in 2010 version.

Now, a maintenance utility which loads data from a mainframe dump is getting blocked by a "SELECT 1 on Patient_Clinic_Visits" when the Access 2003 version is running somewhere. What I can't find, is where that "SELECT 1 on Patient_Clinic_visits" is coming from.

I have looked in all the module code, and all the queries, but can't find anything like that.

I assume it must therefore be in the frontend form, but how do iI search that without looking through all the objects and controls of that form for RecordSource with some SQL code in it?

cheers,

JonHD

Comment: Can you please add some code/SQL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Access menu select Database Tools->Database Documenter. There, select all objects and push OK. It will take some time, but then you will be presented with a report that lists everything in your database, including the code at the end.

The report could be quite big for big databases.

You can export the report to Word (there is an option for it). There, search for your string. (I think it should be "SELECT 1 **from** Patient_Clinic_visits")

Comment: Thanks Cha.. in the end I used the followin routine:

Answer (score 1):

In the end I searched some other questions and thought about programmatically dumping the likely offending information. This is my concoction of two different answers to do what I want. Do to the limits of the Instant Window in VBA over how many lines it will keep from a Debug.Print, I have used WScript object to dump to a log file.

The code basically:

- opens each form in the database in turn
- dumps its RecordSource description
- then for each control on its form, dumps relevant information that *MAY* contain SQL in some way
- note: I use the fact that a Writeline (some code) that causes and error will fail and not write to avoid a lot of testing for different control types for which properties to dump or not dump.
- then closed the forms
- then it goes through all the queries in the database, and dumps SQL code

(Note1: in the end this didn't find the answer to my problem - see my other recent question!!)

(Note2: this was a quick and dirty script. I noticed the first time it ran the WriteStream didn't write anything, even though it on Step ing through the code it seemed to be doing something. Anyhow when I ran it again it worked. Haven't taken the time to debug why!).

```
Function DumpFormsAndQueries()

        Dim obj As AccessObject
        Dim objctrl As Control
        Dim frm As Form
        Dim dbs As Object


        Dim fsoSysObj    As FileSystemObject
        Dim filFile      As Object
        Dim txsStream    As TextStream
        Dim strPath      As String

        Set dbs = Application.CurrentProject

        Set fsoSysObj = New FileSystemObject

        ' Return Windows Temp folder.

        strPath = "C:\Temp\"

        On Error Resume Next
        ' See if file already exists.
        Set filFile = fsoSysObj.GetFile(strPath & "Database_Form_dump.Log")
        ' If not, then create it.
        If Err <> 0 Then
            Set filFile = fsoSysObj.CreateTextFile(strPath & "Database_Form_dump.Log")
        End If

        Debug.Print ">> dumping to: " & strPath & "Database_form_dump.log"

        Set txsStream = filFile.OpenAsTextStream(ForAppending)

        For Each obj In dbs.AllForms

            DoCmd.OpenForm obj.name, acDesign
            Set frm = Forms(obj.name)

            Debug.Print ">>>> dump form: " & obj.name

            txsStream.WriteLine "====================================================================="
            txsStream.WriteLine "Form        : " & obj.name
            txsStream.WriteLine "RecordSource: " & frm.RecordSource
            txsStream.WriteLine "====================================================================="

            For Each objctrl In frm.Controls

                txsStream.WriteLine "                 --------------------------------------------------"
                txsStream.WriteLine "                 : " & objctrl.name & " Type = " & TypeName(objctrl)
                txsStream.WriteLine "                 --------------------------------------------------"
                On Error Resume Next
                txsStream.WriteLine "                 >>>> Recordsource: (" & objctrl.RecordSource & ")"
                txsStream.WriteLine "                 >>>> Controlsource: (" & objctrl.ControlSource & ")"
                txsStream.WriteLine "                 >>>> Rowsource: (" & objctrl.RowSource & ")"
                txsStream.WriteLine "                 >>>> Caption: (" & objctrl.Caption & ")"
                txsStream.WriteLine "                 >>>> Text: (" & objctrl.Text & ")"
                txsStream.WriteBlankLines 1


            Next objctrl


            DoCmd.Close acForm, obj.name, acSaveNo

             txsStream.WriteBlankLines 3

        Next obj

            txsStream.WriteLine "====================================================================="
            txsStream.WriteLine "   Q U E R I E S - in database"
            txsStream.WriteLine "====================================================================="

        Dim db As DAO.Database
        Dim qdf As DAO.QueryDef

        Set db = CurrentDb()
        For Each qdf In db.QueryDefs
            txsStream.WriteLine "Query: " & qdf.name

            txsStream.WriteLine "SQL (start) ---------------------------------------------------- "
            txsStream.WriteLine qdf.sql
            txsStream.WriteLine "SQL (end) ---------------------------------------------------- "
        Next qdf
        Set qdf = Nothing
        Set db = Nothing


        txsStream.Close

        Debug.Print ">> ended"

End Function
```